# How to integrate OSG and Qt together on vs 2015

Tags: qt, 3d, qt5.6

I want integrate Qt 5.6 and osg 3.4 with vs 2015.

I try many times but still failed.
Does anyone integrate them successfully?

Comment: Could you provide some example code showing what you've tried, and the issues/errors you've encountered?

Comment: I just use the osg example osgviewqt https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/blob/master/examples/osgviewerQt/osgviewerQt.cpp. when I debug this, there will be an exception {Exception thrown at 0x0FEE432F (osg130-osgQt.dll) in MYTEST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000027.} for return new this line osgQt::GraphicsWindowQt(traits.get());

Answer (score 0):

maybe use a wrong lib

you need to use a lib ending with "d" in debug(e.g. osgQtd.lib), and without "d" in release (e.g. osgQt.lib)